# Firebase hosting application deploy

Tags: firebase, vuejs2, webdeploy

I tried to deploy my application using Firebase (in build folder I have an index.html file) but I get the following error:

[image]

Does anyone know what might had gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That's actually the default content in the automatically generated `index.html` file by the Firebase CLI when you initialize your project. That's not an error; If you already have HTML ready to go, just paste it inside the `index.html` file inside your `build` folder.

Your screenshot is showing the local `index.html` file, make sure to deploy your site by running `firebase deploy --only hosting`; And also double check your [public](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#public) attribute within your `firebase.json` file is configured to take the `build` folder.

Comment: So which steps am I missing - I need to replace index.html file with the one from my project and then what?

Comment: Then deploy your site by running `firebase deploy --only hosting`